# Why does java.time.ZoneId not implement the Comparable interface?

Tags: java

Just out of curiosity, why shouldn't I be able to compare time zones?

One timezone could be -2:00 related to UTC while another one would be +2:00 for example.
Why not consider those as -2:00 < +2:00 and so on?

Comment: Would that be useful in some way?

Comment: @khelwood of course, e.g. efficient search.

Comment: "One timezone could be -2:00 related to UTC while another one would be +2:00 for example." Yes, you can give examples where the zones are *easy* to compare. What about ones that *aren't* easy to compare. Consider America/New_York and Brazil/Acre for example - between (say) the years 2000-2010, both varied between UTC-4 and UTC-5. Sometimes both were UTC-4. Sometimes both were UTC-5. Sometimes New York was UTC-4 when Acre was UTC-5, sometimes it was the other way round. How should those two zones be sorted?

Comment: If two ZoneIds have the same offset during some parts of the year, and different offsets at other times of the year, how do you expect them to compare?

Comment: There is no linear order of time zones, neither in time or latitude. Think of DST, and country geography. Only an actual instance, ZonedDateTime is comparable. At some point in time, like new years eve, one may arrange time zones where some then compare "equal."

Comment: America/Asuncion time zone is at offset -04:00 in July and -03:00 in January because of summer time (on the southern hemisphere). America/Glace_Bay is opposite, -04:00 in January and -03:00 in July. Which should be the natural ordering of these two time zones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

To sort `ZoneId` objects (time zones), you must specify a moment for which you want the offset (`ZoneOffset`) in effect in each time zone.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.now();
record OffsetForZone( ZoneId zoneId , ZoneOffset offset ) { }
List < OffsetForZone > results =
        ZoneId
                .getAvailableZoneIds()
                .stream()
                .map(
                        ( String zone ) -> new OffsetForZone( ZoneId.of( zone ) , ZoneId.of( zone ).getRules().getOffset( instant ) )
                )
                .sorted(
                        Comparator
                                .comparing( OffsetForZone :: offset ).reversed()
                                .thenComparing( ( OffsetForZone o ) -> o.zoneId.getId() )
                )
                .toList();
```

> Zones sorted by offset in effect at 2021-09-08T08:51:02.939266Z is: [OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT+12, offset=-12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT+11, offset=-11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Midway, offset=-11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Niue, offset=-11:00], …

## Time zones cannot be sorted

An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, nothing more.

A time zone, in contrast, is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians. So a time zone may have *many* offsets, only one of which is in effect at any moment.

So it makes no sense to order time zones by offset, unless you specify a particular moment. And even then, many time zones may coincidentally share the same offset at any particular moment.

You asked:

> One timezone could be -2:00 related to UTC while another one would be +2:00 for example. Why not consider those as -2:00 < +2:00 and so on?

Because those facts could be true for one moment but not another moment. Those zones may use a different offset on a different date and time.

## Code example

Here is some code to sort time zones by their offset in use at a particular moment. We will capture the current moment, as seen in UTC. For that we use the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Get a set of all the time zone identifiers.

```
Set < String > zones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
```

For each of those zones, we need to determine the current offset. We need to store that info in objects, collected for sorting. In Java 16+, we can use a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) to briefly write that class.

```
record OffsetForZone( ZoneId zoneId , ZoneOffset offset ) { }
```

Loop all the zone ids, getting the [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) for each. With that `ZoneId`, get the rules for than zone. Ask the rules for offset in effect at our specific moment. Record each `ZoneId` and is [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) for that moment in a list.

```java
for ( String zone : zones )
{
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( zone );
    ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();
    ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( instant );
    OffsetForZone offsetForZone = new OffsetForZone( zoneId , offset );
    results.add( offsetForZone );
}
```

Being simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds, the [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). This means we can sort on `ZoneOffset`, unlike `ZoneId`.

We want to sort first by the offset. Secondarily, for those zones sharing the same offset in effect at that moment, we want to sort alphabetically by the zone ID.

The [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) class makes such sorting quite easy, along with the [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) method.

```java
results.sort(
        Comparator
                .comparing( OffsetForZone :: offset )
                .thenComparing( ( OffsetForZone o ) -> o.zoneId.getId() )
);
```

If desired, add a [`.reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()) call to sort in opposite direction.

```java
results.sort(
        Comparator
                .comparing( OffsetForZone :: offset ).reversed()
                .thenComparing( ( OffsetForZone o ) -> o.zoneId.getId() )
);
```

Usually best to return an [unmodifiable list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable).

```
results = List.copyOf( results ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "Zones sorted by offset in effect at " + instant + " is: " + results );
```

When run you will see something like the following. (Abbreviated to fit text limits of Stack Overflow.)

```
Zones sorted by offset in effect at 2021-09-08T06:40:09.461149Z is: [OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-14, offset=+14:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Kiritimati, offset=+14:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-13, offset=+13:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Apia, offset=+13:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Enderbury, offset=+13:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Fakaofo, offset=+13:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Tongatapu, offset=+13:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=NZ-CHAT, offset=+12:45], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Chatham, offset=+12:45], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/McMurdo, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/South_Pole, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Anadyr, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Kamchatka, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-12, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Kwajalein, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=NZ, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Auckland, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Fiji, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Funafuti, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Kwajalein, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Majuro, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Nauru, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Tarawa, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Wake, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Wallis, offset=+12:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/Casey, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Magadan, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Sakhalin, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Srednekolymsk, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-11, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Bougainville, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Efate, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Guadalcanal, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Kosrae, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Norfolk, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Noumea, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Pohnpei, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Ponape, offset=+11:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/LHI, offset=+10:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Lord_Howe, offset=+10:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/DumontDUrville, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/Macquarie, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Ust-Nera, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Vladivostok, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/ACT, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Brisbane, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Canberra, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Currie, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Hobart, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Lindeman, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Melbourne, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/NSW, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Queensland, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Sydney, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Tasmania, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Victoria, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-10, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Chuuk, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Guam, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Port_Moresby, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Saipan, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Truk, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Yap, offset=+10:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Adelaide, offset=+09:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Broken_Hill, offset=+09:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Darwin, offset=+09:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/North, offset=+09:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/South, offset=+09:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Yancowinna, offset=+09:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Chita, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Dili, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Jayapura, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Khandyga, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Pyongyang, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Seoul, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Tokyo, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Yakutsk, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-9, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Japan, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Pacific/Palau, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=ROK, offset=+09:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Eucla, offset=+08:45], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Brunei, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Choibalsan, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Chongqing, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Chungking, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Harbin, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Hong_Kong, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Irkutsk, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Kuching, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Macao, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Macau, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Makassar, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Manila, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Shanghai, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Singapore, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Taipei, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Ujung_Pandang, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Ulaanbaatar, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Ulan_Bator, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/Perth, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Australia/West, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-8, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Hongkong, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=PRC, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Singapore, offset=+08:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/Davis, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Bangkok, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Barnaul, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Hovd, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Jakarta, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Krasnoyarsk, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Novokuznetsk, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Novosibirsk, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Phnom_Penh, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Pontianak, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Saigon, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Tomsk, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Vientiane, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-7, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Christmas, offset=+07:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Rangoon, offset=+06:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Yangon, offset=+06:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Cocos, offset=+06:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/Vostok, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Almaty, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Bishkek, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Dacca, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Dhaka, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Kashgar, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Omsk, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Qostanay, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Thimbu, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Thimphu, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Urumqi, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-6, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Chagos, offset=+06:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Kathmandu, offset=+05:45], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Katmandu, offset=+05:45], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Calcutta, offset=+05:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Colombo, offset=+05:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Kolkata, offset=+05:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/Mawson, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Aqtau, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Aqtobe, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Ashgabat, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Ashkhabad, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Atyrau, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Dushanbe, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Karachi, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Oral, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Qyzylorda, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Samarkand, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Tashkent, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Yekaterinburg, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-5, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Kerguelen, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Maldives, offset=+05:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Kabul, offset=+04:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Tehran, offset=+04:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Iran, offset=+04:30], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Baku, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Dubai, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Muscat, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Tbilisi, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Yerevan, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-4, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Astrakhan, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Samara, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Saratov, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Ulyanovsk, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Mahe, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Mauritius, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Reunion, offset=+04:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Addis_Ababa, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Asmara, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Asmera, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Dar_es_Salaam, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Djibouti, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Kampala, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Mogadishu, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Nairobi, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/Syowa, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Aden, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Amman, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Baghdad, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Bahrain, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Beirut, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Damascus, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Famagusta, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Gaza, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Hebron, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Istanbul, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Jerusalem, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Kuwait, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Nicosia, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Qatar, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Riyadh, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Asia/Tel_Aviv, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=EET, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-3, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Athens, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Bucharest, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Chisinau, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Helsinki, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Istanbul, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Kiev, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Kirov, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Mariehamn, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Minsk, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Moscow, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Nicosia, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Riga, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Simferopol, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Sofia, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Tallinn, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Tiraspol, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Uzhgorod, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Vilnius, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Volgograd, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Zaporozhye, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Antananarivo, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Comoro, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Indian/Mayotte, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Israel, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Turkey, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=W-SU, offset=+03:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Blantyre, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Bujumbura, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Cairo, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Ceuta, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Gaborone, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Harare, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Johannesburg, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Juba, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Khartoum, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Kigali, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Lubumbashi, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Lusaka, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Maputo, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Maseru, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Mbabane, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Tripoli, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Windhoek, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Antarctica/Troll, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Arctic/Longyearbyen, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=CET, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Egypt, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-2, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Amsterdam, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Andorra, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Belgrade, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Berlin, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Bratislava, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Brussels, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Budapest, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Busingen, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Copenhagen, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Gibraltar, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Kaliningrad, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Ljubljana, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Luxembourg, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Madrid, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Malta, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Monaco, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Oslo, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Paris, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Podgorica, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Prague, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Rome, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/San_Marino, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Sarajevo, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Skopje, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Stockholm, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Tirane, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Vaduz, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Vatican, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Vienna, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Warsaw, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Zagreb, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Zurich, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Libya, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=MET, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Poland, offset=+02:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Algiers, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Bangui, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Brazzaville, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Casablanca, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Douala, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/El_Aaiun, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Kinshasa, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Lagos, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Libreville, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Luanda, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Malabo, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Ndjamena, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Niamey, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Porto-Novo, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Tunis, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Atlantic/Canary, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Atlantic/Faeroe, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Atlantic/Faroe, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Atlantic/Madeira, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Eire, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-1, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Belfast, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Dublin, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Guernsey, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Isle_of_Man, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Jersey, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/Lisbon, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Europe/London, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=GB, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=GB-Eire, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Portugal, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=WET, offset=+01:00], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Abidjan, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Accra, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Bamako, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Banjul, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Bissau, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Conakry, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Dakar, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Freetown, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Lome, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Monrovia, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Nouakchott, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Ouagadougou, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Sao_Tome, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Africa/Timbuktu, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=America/Danmarkshavn, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=America/Scoresbysund, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Atlantic/Azores, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Atlantic/Reykjavik, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Atlantic/St_Helena, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT+0, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT-0, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/GMT0, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/Greenwich, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/UCT, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/UTC, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/Universal, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Etc/Zulu, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=GMT, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=GMT0, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Greenwich, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Iceland, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=UCT, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=UTC, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Universal, offset=Z], OffsetForZone[zoneId=Zulu, offset=Z], …
```

Answer (score 7):

Since [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) encode [Time Zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) and it change the offset respect UTC, there is not an [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

That's why [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) implements `Comparable<ZoneOffset>` since it is a fixed offset.

**(Additional note)**

For example:

```
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Belem -03:00/-03:00
```

where sometimes the order of `Newfoundland ~ Belem` is `-02:30 > -03:00` but sometimes is `-03:30 < -03:00`.

A simple way to list all (from now up to four years) zone id pairs where the offset order change from `A < B` to `B < A` could be:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class ZoneIdOrderChanges {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        // all zones
        List<ZoneId> zonesId = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream().map(ZoneId::of).collect(toList());

        // all combinations two by two without repetition
        final List<Tuple<ZoneId, ZoneId>> pairs = IntStream.range(1, zonesId.size()).boxed().flatMap(a ->
                IntStream.range(a + 1, zonesId.size()).mapToObj(b ->
                        new Tuple<>(zonesId.get(a), zonesId.get(b)))).collect(toList());

        // from now up to 4 years after now
        OffsetDateTime t0 = OffsetDateTime.now();
        OffsetDateTime t = OffsetDateTime.now();
        OffsetDateTime sentry = t.plus(4, ChronoUnit.YEARS);

        BiFunction<OffsetDateTime, Integer, Integer> compareZones = (d, i) ->
                Integer.compare(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(d.toInstant(), pairs.get(i).a).getOffset()
                        .compareTo(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(d.toInstant(), pairs.get(i).b).getOffset()), 0);

        Function<OffsetDateTime, int[]> forder = z -> IntStream
                .range(0, pairs.size())
                .map(i -> compareZones.apply(z, i))
                .toArray();

        int[] order = forder.apply(t);

        Set<String> examples = new HashSet<>();

        while (t.compareTo(sentry) <= 0) {
            int[] o = forder.apply(t);
            if (Arrays.compare(order, o) != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
                    // only interested in not equals cases
                    if (order[i] != o[i] && order[i] != 0 && o[i] != 0) {
                        final OffsetDateTime tt = t;
                        String example = Stream.of(pairs.get(i).a, pairs.get(i).b)
                                .map(z -> String.format("%s %s/%s",
                                        z.getId(),
                                        ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(t0.toInstant(), z).getOffset(),
                                        ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(tt.toInstant(), z).getOffset()))
                                .collect(joining(" ~ "));
                        if (!examples.contains(example)) {
                            examples.add(example);
                            System.out.println(example);
                        }
                    }
            }
            t = t.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        }

    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Tuple<A, B> {
        private A a;
        private B b;
    }

}
```

with output (for that time interval and current rules)

```
Asia/Yerevan +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Asia/Yerevan +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Etc/GMT-4 +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Etc/GMT-4 +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Asia/Dubai +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Asia/Dubai +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Indian/Reunion +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Indian/Reunion +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Indian/Mauritius +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Indian/Mauritius +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Europe/Saratov +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Europe/Saratov +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Europe/Samara +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Europe/Samara +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Indian/Mahe +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Indian/Mahe +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Asia/Baku +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Asia/Baku +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Asia/Muscat +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Asia/Muscat +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Europe/Volgograd +04:00/+04:00 ~ Iran +04:30/+03:30
Europe/Volgograd +04:00/+04:00 ~ Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30
Iran +04:30/+03:30 ~ Europe/Astrakhan +04:00/+04:00
Iran +04:30/+03:30 ~ Asia/Tbilisi +04:00/+04:00
Iran +04:30/+03:30 ~ Europe/Ulyanovsk +04:00/+04:00
Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30 ~ Europe/Astrakhan +04:00/+04:00
Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30 ~ Asia/Tbilisi +04:00/+04:00
Asia/Tehran +04:30/+03:30 ~ Europe/Ulyanovsk +04:00/+04:00
Pacific/Fakaofo +13:00/+13:00 ~ NZ-CHAT +12:45/+13:45
Pacific/Fakaofo +13:00/+13:00 ~ Pacific/Chatham +12:45/+13:45
NZ-CHAT +12:45/+13:45 ~ Pacific/Enderbury +13:00/+13:00
NZ-CHAT +12:45/+13:45 ~ Pacific/Tongatapu +13:00/+13:00
NZ-CHAT +12:45/+13:45 ~ Etc/GMT-13 +13:00/+13:00
Pacific/Chatham +12:45/+13:45 ~ Pacific/Enderbury +13:00/+13:00
Pacific/Chatham +12:45/+13:45 ~ Pacific/Tongatapu +13:00/+13:00
Pacific/Chatham +12:45/+13:45 ~ Etc/GMT-13 +13:00/+13:00
Pacific/Yap +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Yap +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Yap +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Yap +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Port_Moresby +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Port_Moresby +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Port_Moresby +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Port_Moresby +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Chuuk +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Queensland +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Guam +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Truk +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Asia/Vladivostok +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Saipan +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Antarctica/DumontDUrville +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Brisbane +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Etc/GMT-10 +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Asia/Ust-Nera +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Yancowinna +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Lindeman +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Chuuk +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Queensland +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Guam +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Truk +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Asia/Vladivostok +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Saipan +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Antarctica/DumontDUrville +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Brisbane +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Etc/GMT-10 +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Asia/Ust-Nera +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Adelaide +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Lindeman +10:00/+10:00
Pacific/Chuuk +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Chuuk +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Australia/Queensland +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30
Australia/Queensland +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Guam +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Truk +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Asia/Vladivostok +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Pacific/Saipan +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Antarctica/DumontDUrville +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Brisbane +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Etc/GMT-10 +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Asia/Ust-Nera +10:00/+10:00
Australia/Broken_Hill +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Lindeman +10:00/+10:00
Pacific/Guam +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Truk +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Asia/Vladivostok +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Pacific/Saipan +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Antarctica/DumontDUrville +10:00/+10:00 ~ Australia/South +09:30/+10:30
Australia/South +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Brisbane +10:00/+10:00
Australia/South +09:30/+10:30 ~ Etc/GMT-10 +10:00/+10:00
Australia/South +09:30/+10:30 ~ Asia/Ust-Nera +10:00/+10:00
Australia/South +09:30/+10:30 ~ Australia/Lindeman +10:00/+10:00
Etc/GMT-1 +01:00/+01:00 ~ Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z
Africa/Tunis +01:00/+01:00 ~ Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z
Africa/Malabo +01:00/+01:00 ~ Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z
America/Godthab -02:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-02:30
America/Godthab -02:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-02:30
Africa/Lagos +01:00/+01:00 ~ Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z
Africa/Algiers +01:00/+01:00 ~ Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z
Africa/Ndjamena +01:00/+01:00 ~ Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Libreville +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/El_Aaiun +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Douala +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Brazzaville +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Porto-Novo +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Casablanca +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Luanda +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Kinshasa +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Bangui +01:00/+01:00
Antarctica/Troll +02:00/Z ~ Africa/Niamey +01:00/+01:00
America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00 ~ SystemV/AST4ADT -03:00/-04:00
Chile/Continental -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
Chile/Continental -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Catamarca -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Catamarca -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
Canada/Atlantic -03:00/-04:00 ~ America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00
America/Argentina/Cordoba -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Cordoba -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Araguaina -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Araguaina -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Salta -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Salta -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
Etc/GMT+3 -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
Etc/GMT+3 -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Montevideo -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Montevideo -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
Brazil/East -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
Brazil/East -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Mendoza -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Mendoza -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Catamarca -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Catamarca -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Cordoba -03:00/-03:00 ~ America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30
America/Cordoba -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Sao_Paulo -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/Jujuy -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Cayenne -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Recife -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Buenos_Aires -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Paramaribo -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Mendoza -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Santarem -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Maceio -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ Atlantic/Stanley -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ Antarctica/Rothera -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/San_Luis -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Santiago -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/Ushuaia -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ Antarctica/Palmer -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Punta_Arenas -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Fortaleza -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/La_Rioja -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Belem -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Jujuy -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Bahia -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/San_Juan -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/Tucuman -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Rosario -03:00/-03:00
America/St_Johns -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires -03:00/-03:00
America/Sao_Paulo -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Argentina/Jujuy -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Cayenne -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Recife -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Buenos_Aires -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Paramaribo -03:00/-03:00 ~ Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30
America/Moncton -03:00/-04:00 ~ America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Mendoza -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Santarem -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Maceio -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ Atlantic/Stanley -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ Antarctica/Rothera -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/San_Luis -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Santiago -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/Ushuaia -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ Antarctica/Palmer -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Punta_Arenas -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Fortaleza -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/La_Rioja -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Belem -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Jujuy -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Bahia -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/San_Juan -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/Tucuman -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Rosario -03:00/-03:00
Canada/Newfoundland -02:30/-03:30 ~ America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires -03:00/-03:00
America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00 ~ Atlantic/Bermuda -03:00/-04:00
America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00 ~ America/Halifax -03:00/-04:00
America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00 ~ America/Glace_Bay -03:00/-04:00
America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00 ~ America/Thule -03:00/-04:00
America/Asuncion -04:00/-03:00 ~ America/Goose_Bay -03:00/-04:00
America/Atka -09:00/-10:00 ~ Pacific/Marquesas -09:30/-09:30
Pacific/Marquesas -09:30/-09:30 ~ America/Adak -09:00/-10:00
Pacific/Marquesas -09:30/-09:30 ~ US/Aleutian -09:00/-10:00
```